# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module in FE unit tests when adding typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, vuejs3

We have a legacy project that's using AngularJS + Typescript. It has a suite of Jasmine unit tests that was working fine. Recently, we've successfully added a new application with Vue3 in the legacy one.

When we introduced Typescript in the new app, the FE tests started to fail with the following error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ns due to:
> [$injector:nomod] Module 'ns' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Does anyone have any idea on what would be the cause for this and how to fix it?